# Как из теста на одном холсте , перенести текст на другой холст?

Tags: unity3d

вот процедура из скрипт привязанного к другому объекту

```
public GameObject EndMenu;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
        {
            if (co.name == "PacMan")
            {
                Destroy(co.gameObject);
                EndMenu.SetActive(true);
                Time.timeScale = 0;
    
            }
        }
```

Как текст из  источника поместить в приемник ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

GameObject.Find("EndGameConvas/EndGamePanel/Score").GetComponent().text = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Score").GetComponent().text;